# How do I set the 'Deletable' property of an impoint in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

My goal is to create a non deletable impoint on an predefined image axes handle. Therefore I would like to do something like this:

```
point = impoint(handles.axesImage, [640 480]);
set(point, 'Deletable', false)
```

And MATLAB 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a) returns:

```
Error using matlab.graphics.primitive.Group/set
There is no Deletable property on the Group class.
Error in imroi/set (line 335)
set(obj.h_group,varargin{2:end});
```

But asking for point I get:

```
>>point

point = 

impoint with properties:

Deletable: 1
```

What is my mistake? And how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, in MATLAB 2014b or higher, this just works:

```
point.Deletable=false;
```

While I get the error with `set`. Bug maybe?

Comment: @AndreasSchwab We are far enough from 2014 version as to safely start coding with the new object format for graphic stuff, so I suggest dropping the `set` `get` syntax and directly accessing the attributes of graphic objects. Its just easier and clearer.

Comment: Some more points: ***(1)*** 'Deleteable' property doesn't exist in the documentation of R2014a.  ***(2)*** The use of 'Deleteable' property is documented  with dot notation since R2014b. So just follow the doc.  ***(3)*** if you enter `get(point)`, you won't see the `Deleteable` property. If you want to use the `get` `set` approach, you can set the `Visible` property to `'off'` which is here: `point.UIContextMenu.Children(1).Visible`. But it will be an overkill